# Difference between user principle name and logon name in active directory

Tags: windows, server, active-directory, windows-services

I am learning active directory and came across UPN , logon name and Sam Account name.
So SAM account name is Pre Windows 2000 (ie Windows NT). So it is clear , Logon name is used when user is trying login in one of the domain computers , And then there is User Principle Name which according to windows documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties#userprincipalname) , is the Logon name itself and it is confirmed by editing UPN in attribute editor affects the logon name. But in many online blogs and articles they mention these two things as two different field ? So my question is UPN and logon name different if so what is the difference between them ?

Edit : [link](http://blog.schertz.name/2012/08/understanding-active-directory-naming-formats/) for the blog where it says logon name and UPN are different

Answer (score 0):

AD (at least by default) doesn't have a dedicated account attribute which reflects the "user logon name". The term "user logon name" just refers to the part of the UPN which is in front of the @.

The relevant AD attributes which can be used for logon are either the "sAMAccountName" in combination with the non-qualified (legacy) domain name or the "userPrincipalName", which is a concatenation of the user logon name and the qualified (DNS) domain name.